# how to plot actual and predicted values?

Tags: r

Im a student of statistics and i would like kindly request for some assistance. I would like to plot predicted values together with actual values of the course of 100 days in my dataset:

Sample Data:

```
             set.seet(1010)
             count<-rpois(100, lambda = 5)
             mood<- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = .7)
             temp<-rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 5)
             wind<-rbinom(100, size = 3, prob = .7)
             days<-seq(1,100,by=1)
             df<-data.frame(count,mood,temp,wind,days)
```

Plotting actual values during 100 days:

```
             plot(count~days,type="l")
```

Regression:

```
             poisson <- glm(count ~mood+wind+temp)
```

Condition on my predictors and otaining predicted values:

```
             hyp<- c(1,1,3,20)
             coeff.p1 <- poisson$coefficients
             XB <- hyp%*%coeff.p1
             predv.y <- exp(XB)
             predv.y
```

May be there is a way to predict values for all observations as for example:

```
              coeff.p1 <- poisson$coefficients
              XB <- c(,2:4)%*%t(coeff.p1)
```

I intend to multiply with columns 2:4 by always get

```
              Error in c(, 2:4) : argument 1 is empty
```

Here Im stuck. As a result I would like to obtain predicted values and actuall values for 100 day on one plot.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object `poisson` is of class `glm`, so it has a `predict` method when given any data.

```
poisson <- glm(count ~mood+temp+ wind)
df$pred<-predict(poisson,df[,2:4])
plot(df$days,df$count)
lines(df$days, df$pred,type='l',col='blue')
```

Comment: first of all thank you. is there a possibility to plot both the predicted and the actual values in one plot?

Comment: Yes, you can plot the data with `plot` and then use `lines` to overlay the prediction, as shown above. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set.seed(1010)
count<-rpois(100, lambda = 5)
mood<- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = .7)
temp<-rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 5)
wind<-rbinom(100, size = 3, prob = .7)
days<-seq(1,100,by=1)
df<-data.frame(count,mood,temp,wind,days)
poisson <- glm(count ~ mood+wind+temp
               , family = poisson() #specify your model type
               , data=df)

# Calculate the predicted
phat.poisson <- predprob(poisson)  # for each subj, prob of observing each value
phat.poisson.mn <- apply(phat.poisson, 2, mean) # mean predicted probs

#your plot of observed vs. predicted
hist(count, prob = TRUE, col = "grey60", breaks=seq(-0.5, 12.5, 1), xlab = "Counts",main = NULL, ylim=c(0, .20))
lines(x = seq(0, 12, 1), y = phat.poisson.mn, lty=2, lwd=2, col="red")
points(x = seq(0, 12, 1), y = phat.poisson.mn, cex=1, pch=16, col="red")
```

Comment: hi thank you. why is it not possible to multiply each row of my predictors with the coefficients coeff.p1 <- poisson$coefficients
              XB <- c(,2:4)%*%t(coeff.p1) ?

Comment: I think you should have a look at the documentation found in `help(expand.grid)` and `help(predict.glm)`. Perhaps also familiarise yourself with the class of object returned by `glm`.

Comment: @Mamba You're on the right track - the prediction you want will be the dot product of the `coef` values and each row of data values. However, `poisson$coef` has a value for `Intercept` which is a global offset, not related to just one predictor. The point is, `poisson$coef` is of length 4, but each row of your data is of length 3, `df[,2:4]`. So you could do this `prediction<-poisson$coeff[1]+ poisson$coef[2:4] %*% t(df[,2:4] )`.  But as I mention below, all of that is the same as the `predict()` method.