# Compare predicted values and actual values by Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I uses Caret to get a prediction for electricity usage per day. I am wondering if there is a way to plot both predicted data and the actual data to inspect the difference.

I check this post, but I didn't find the solution I want.
[how to plot actual and predicted values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567922/how-to-plot-actual-and-predicted-values)

Assume two list of numbers.

```
actual <- [1,2,3,4]
predicted <- [1.3,2,3.1,4]
```

Is there a simply way to plot the two line to observe the difference?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean just `plot(actual, predicted)`? Also what you've provided is not valid R code. Literal arrays should look like `actual <- c(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: Maybe something like `plot(day, actual); points(day, predicted, col = "blue")`. It is better to explain the question clearly with an example, when possible.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned using `caret`, so there must be some model you're trying to fit.  if correct, there exists a model object and you could use [plotObsVsPred](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/plotObsVsPred) function. Here is a simplified example from help link:

```
# regression example
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)

plsFit <- train(BostonHousing[1:100, -c(4, 14)], 
                BostonHousing$medv[1:100], 
                "pls")

predVals <- extractPrediction(list(plsFit), 
                              testX = BostonHousing[101:200, -c(4, 14)], 
                              testY = BostonHousing$medv[101:200]) 

plotObsVsPred(predVals)
```

[image]